# Password change broke SQL ODBC connection

Tags: sql-server-2008, odbc

I have a legacy HR application using a SQL database.  The vendor provides NO support.  A sql account password changed and apparently it was the account used for the ODBC connection.  No one knew the old password.  Now the HR app can't connect to Database.  Any suggestions on how to reconfigure the ODBC connection with the new password?

Thanks a million for any help!

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoHEI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you get on the server and look at ODBC connections? Check for the HRsql connection, locate the user, and reset his connection inside of the database.

Comment: I can get onto the server, and into the sql database.  Which do you mean to look at ODBC connections?

Comment: And using which tool?  Visual Studio, SSMS, or WIndows ODBC connections?  THanks.

Comment: I"m assuming you are using Windows Server. So at desktop type ODBC or Control Panel > ODBC and then find your connection. It's in system or file tab, most likely not user. Then open it and look at the user and simply change password in SQL Server and connection

Comment: https://imgur.com/zGMXnZi then it's either in system or file dsn tab. HRSQL needs a new password in sql server then change it in the configuration!!! Bueno?